# Angular-Gantt - Movable Plugin not Working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs, gantt-chart

I'm attempting to use the [movable plugin for angular-gantt](https://angular-gantt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/movable/).

So far, I've managed to get a simple gantt chart together, but I have not been able to get the movable plugin working.

The gantt lines are visible, but I can not get them to move.

I have tried removing all other plugins except for the movable plugin and the gantts data, however I still got nowhere.

The problem prints no errors in the console.

I have researched around to find an answer, but it seems that angular-gantt is an uncommon module for AngularJS.

I am very new to JavaScript and Angular in particular. Any help would be greatly appreciated, even just pointing me in the right direction.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Angular Test Doc</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Vendor/angular-gantt-1.2.6/assets/angular-gantt.css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Vendor/angular-gantt-1.2.6/assets/angular-gantt-movable-plugin.css">
        <style>

        </style>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController as data">
        <div gantt data=data>
            <gantt-movable enabled="true"></gantt-movable>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Vendor/AngularJS/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Vendor/Moment/moment.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Vendor/angular-moment/angular-moment.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Vendor/angular-gantt-1.2.6/assets/angular-gantt.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Vendor/angular-gantt-1.2.6/assets/angular-gantt-movable-plugin.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module("myApp", ['gantt', 'gantt.movable'])
        .controller("myController", function($scope) {
            $scope.data = [
                {name: "row1", tasks: [
                    {name: 'task1', from: new Date("October 13, 2014 13:45:00"), to: new Date("October 14, 2014 11:13:00"), movable: true},
                    {name: 'task2', from: new Date("October 15, 2014 11:13:00"), to: new Date("October 17, 2014 11:13:00")}
                ]},
                {name: "row2again", tasks: [
                    {name: 'task3', from: new Date("October 13, 2014 11:13:00"), to: new Date("October 17, 2014 11:13:00")}
                ]}

            ]
        });
    </script>
</html>
```